# PyTorch: Getting ModuleNotFoundError while loading model

Tags: pytorch, torch

I have a pre-trained **yolov7.pt** model which I tried to load using `torch.load()`. Below is the complete code I ran.

```py
import torch

model_path = "/content/yolov7/model/yolov7.pt"
model = torch.load(model_path,map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
```

But for some reason, I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-cc86721fbe65> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 
      3 model_path = "/content/yolov7/model/yolov7.pt"
----> 4 model = torch.load(model_path,map_location=torch.device('cpu'))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in find_class(self, mod_name, name)
   1163                     pass
   1164             mod_name = load_module_mapping.get(mod_name, mod_name)
-> 1165             return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
   1166 
   1167     # Load the data (which may in turn use `persistent_load` to load tensors)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

When you trained your model, you declared a class to contain its definitions. `torch.load` needs this exact class definition to be able to load the model weights. You can copy and past the model definition on your code or create a module for it in a different folder.